# It is possible pass the value of an id from a template, to function (AngulasJS2)

Tags: angular

It is possible pass the value of an id from a template, to function (AngulasJS2).

```
 template: `
  <div class="container" *ngFor="#mov of movs">
  ..//
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
  ..//
  (click)="test(id)" [id]="mov"
  > 
  ..//

  ..//
  test(id: string) {
  //test
  var logo1: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(id);
  ..//
  }
```

right now I'm using it and it works,

```
 (click)="test(''+mov)" [id]="mov"
```

but with this code does not work.

```
(click)="test(id)" [id]="mov"
```

I'm sorry for my English

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I would like instead of using (click)="test( '' + mov)", to pass the id value (click)="test(id)"

Comment: But you are assigning `mov` to `[id]`, therefore it doesn't really make a difference when you just pass `mov` (or `''mov`), does it?

Comment: Are outputs the answer? - 11+ mins into this video (starts around 11:15) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlqoPpLMdwY

Comment: I am facing this problem too. In case of a bind function the parameters that gets passed appears to switch types, for example in my case Angular/Typescript was automatically converting my value (mov.id) which is in string to number type. There is some kind of type conversion in play here which I couldn't figure out. The workaround was to force it to string by appending with ''. This is very odd though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a template variable like `#elem` (on a native DOM element, not an Angular component or an element with a directive) you can use it as a reference to the element and then get the id from the element (`elem.id`).

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let mov of movs" >
  ..//
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" #elem
  ..//
    (click)="test(elem.id)" [id]="mov"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this as well:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let mov of movs" >
..//
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" 
 ..//
    (click)="test(mov)" [id]="mov">
```

plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/iFRJI8perdwmWpZoBcvW?p=preview